# How to change the qualifier in the file names of plugins and features

Tags: tycho, p2

I am trying to rename my artifacts in the repository folder of my eclipse-repository module. At the moment they are auto generated like **...1.0.0.v20130315-1927.jar**.

I haven't found any configuration parameter that works. I have tried to use the qualifier setting in the configuration (see [tycho-p2-repository-plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/tycho/sitedocs/tycho-p2/tycho-p2-repository-plugin/assemble-repository-mojo.html)), but it doesn't work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>development.statTool</groupId>
        <artifactId>Application</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>development.statTool</groupId>
    <artifactId>development.statTool.p2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>eclipse-repository</packaging>

    <properties>
        <tycho-version>0.16.0</tycho-version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-p2-repository-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho-version}</version>

                <configuration>
                    <qualifier>abcd</qualifier>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution is to use the tycho-packaging-plugin. Only "disadvantage" changing the build qualifier needs to rebuild all modules contained by the repository.

Here the part out of my parent pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
    <artifactId>tycho-packaging-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${tycho.version}</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>tycho-buildtimestamp-jgit</artifactId>
            <version>${tycho-extras.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <configuration>
        <strictBinIncludes>false</strictBinIncludes>
        <format>'rev${rev}-'yyyyMMdd-HHmm</format>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: This is the correct approach: eclipse-repository only aggregates artifacts in a p2 repository format. The format requires that the file names match their version, so if you want to change the file names, you have to change the versions of the artifacts.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
mvn -Dtycho.mode=maven org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-versions-plugin:set-version -DnewVersion=13.3.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

or simply search text "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT" and replace it with  "13.3.0.1" using Actual Search and Replace tool.